# The POM for org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kinesis_2.11:jar:1.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available when running "mvn package" command

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have inherited a maven project. I am trying to build it using "mvn package" command:

**Error I am getting:**

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kinesis_2.11:jar:1.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (add-source) @ flink-kinesis-consumer ---
[INFO] Source directory: /Users/me/repos/kinesis-analytics-consumer/src/main/scala added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ flink-kinesis-consumer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 8 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ flink-kinesis-consumer ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (default) @ flink-kinesis-consumer ---
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kinesis_2.11:jar:1.8.3
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11:1.8.3 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11:1.8.3 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.11:1.8.3 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.12 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.11:1.8.3 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.11:1.8.3 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.12 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.5 requires scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] /Users/me/repos/kinesis-analytics-consumer/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to /Users/me/repos/kinesis-analytics-consumer/target/classes at 1590969618012
[ERROR] error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/tools/ToolProvider
```

**What I have tried so far:**

1. I have searched stackoverflow for "The POM for org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kinesis_2.11:jar:1.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available". I found that one talks about version 1.6.2 , but solution there did not help me.
2. Using the documentation here:
   https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-and-run-streaming-applications-with-apache-flink-and-amazon-kinesis-data-analytics-for-java-applications/

   I did:

```
  $ wget -qO- https://github.com/apache/flink/archive/release-1.8.3.zip | bsdtar -xf-

  $ cd flink-release-1.8.3

  $mvn clean package -B -DskipTests -Dfast -Pinclude-kinesis -pl flink-connectors/flink-connector-kinesis
```

The above steps ran without errors and it seemed to build flink-connector-kinesis 1.8.3.  But, that did not solve my issue.

**HERE is my pom.xml file:**

(I have replaced my real company name with "mycompany")

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-kinesis-consumer</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Flink Kinesis Consumer</name>
  <url>https://www.mycompany.com/</url>
  <properties>
    <flink.version>1.8.3</flink.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kda.version>1.1.0</kda.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    <aws.sdk.version>1.11.319</aws.sdk.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aws.dynamodbstreams-kinesis-adapter.version>1.5.0</aws.dynamodbstreams-kinesis-adapter.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.727</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>${kda.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
      <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
      <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>org.wb.kinesisanalytics.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
            <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
          <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
          </buildcommands>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
            <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-compiler</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <sourceIncludes>
            <sourceInclude>**/*.scala</sourceInclude>
            <sourceInclude>**/*.java</sourceInclude>
          </sourceIncludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/main/scala</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>add-test-source</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-test-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/test/scala</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scalastyle</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalastyle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>false</verbose>
          <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
          <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
          <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
          <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
          <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
          <configLocation>${project.basedir}/lib/scalastyle_config.xml</configLocation>
          <outputFile>${project.basedir}/scalastyle-output.xml</outputFile>
          <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>add-dependencies-for-IDEA</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>idea.version</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${flink.version}</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${flink.version}</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
          <version>${scala.version}</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

**MY VERSIONS**

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 13.0.2, vendor: N/A, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/13.0.2+8_2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```